# Actualizar existencias sql con un DataGridView C# Visual

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, datagridview

Quiero actualizar existencias de productos que tenga almacenadas a la hora de presionar el botón Registrar.

El sistema funciona así:

Al presionar `Ok` se ingresan los datos del **detalledeCompra** y **Compra** en el `DataGridView`, cada **detalleDeCompra** tiene un respectivo **Insumo**, entre los datos del insumo se encuentra su existencia y quiere que se actualice sumandole la Cantidad comprada del insumo.

[image: Imagen de la pantalla del sistema]

> Trata esto, Update el valor existencia en Insumos sumando la existencia existente con el valor de la columna Cantidad que coincida con la descripción del Insumo

```
 comando = new SqlCommand( "Update Insumos setValues(@Existencia) 
           Where Descripcion = '" + cmbDescripcion.Text + "'", conexion );
        conexion.Open();
        try
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvComprasI.Rows)
            {
                comando.Parameters.Clear();
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Existencia", 
                    Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Cantidad"].Value + "Existencia"));
                comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            conexion.Close();
        }
```

Comment: La sentencia Update en Sql server no lleva el valor a updatear entre paréntesis, sino con un igual. Y ya que usas parámetros, deberías de hacer lo mismo con Descripción, para prevenir Sql inyection